# HTML Input element does not work

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am currently working on an HTML5 game engine and I need to use the Input element. 
First I made a script to create the element dynamically. 
The element it created did not work like an Input element but was nothing more than a simple box. 
So I put the Input element in without using Javascript, simply

```
<input type="text" />
```

It does not work either. It creates an element and it changes the cursor when you hover over it, but you can not write into it. 
Does anyone know what can be the cause of that?

Comment: How does the rest of your js and the html look like? This information might be helpful :)

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/yb3Fy/ If you don't provide more info, it'll be difficult to help

Comment: the input element ist parented to the body. I am using jQuery for a lot of things. The event handlers $(document).mousemove(...); and $(document).keydown(...); and $(document).keyup(); . I am also using requestAnimationFrame for the mainloop. I cant imagine what is interfering with the imput element.    edit: I have been using javascript for years now and the game engine is allready running. now i only wanted to implement UIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is probably some sort of bound key event handler that stops propagation before it reaches the text box. This sound especially likely considering you're working on a game engine.

Check your code for event handlers that might block your key events from reaching the text input. Also make sure that your code doesn't prevent the input from receiving *focus*.

Comment: You were right, thank you very much :D I have removed the jQuery event handlers $(document).mousedown(function{return false;});